# Ubuntu EXTREME size problems at 1920x1080 resolution

Tags: 16.04, display, display-resolution

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my HP laptop that came pre-installed with windows 10.

The resolution of the screen of the display is set to 1920x1080, and the screen is 13.3". Everything - icons, tabs, fonts - is extremely tiny in ubuntu.

I scaled the icons and tabs by changing the scale factor in display settings, but it does not change the fonts. I installed unity tweak tool, and changed the fonts, which now already looks ugly since the fonts do not correspond properly to the icon size. When i open firefox, everything is tiny again. I changed the fonts in firefox, but the tab width still remains tiny. If i open a pdf in browser on firefox, the pdf section bookmarks on the left tab/pane are extremely tiny, and do not increase in size when zoomed. At present, everything is scaled ad-hoc and looks ugly.

*None* of these problems appear in windows 10. Everything mentioned above, in all applications is scaled properly, by default.

My question is -

Is there a way to scale *everything* uniformly in ubuntu 16.04 by keeping 1920x1080 resolution, so that i do not have to ad-hoc scale every individual application?

I do not want to decrease the resolution, else there is no point in using the high resolution screen.

I do not want to revert to windows, but might have to if this cant be done in ubuntu. :(

Comment: why are you using 1920x1080 on a 13' screen? that's approx 200 pixels an inch. it is unlikely that the screen is actually displaying that much resolution, or if it is, the eye isn't that acute.

Comment: at present i am doing it simply because it is allowing me to. It does seem to make a difference while watching a video on youtube. Also, even 4k resolutions on 13.3" were available, so i doubt if the screen isnt displaying it. Also, why is windows able to handle it with complete ease?

Comment: the card has the resolutions available because there is an HDMI port. this does not mean that the screen actually display all 200 pixels an inch. The change in youtube is probably a switch from a lower resolution stream to a HD stream. ie a change in video quality received.

Comment: @I can't address the scaling issue, I'm not a programmer nor am I familiar with the code. It just seems counter productive to use a high resolution then scale everything 200% to see it. First the high resolution requires more memory reserved for the display and uses more GPU time. Second, the scaling uses CPU time.

Comment: thanks for the help and all the information. At present, i am able to see differences even in latex pdfs at the two different resolutions, although extremely slight. I am only surprised since windows has the problem completely solved and ubuntu has not even tried to solve it. Also, i am ok with more memory and cpu time being used to see better things on the screen - that is why i have paid extra money to get high-end memory and cpu.

Comment: windows is also 3 times larger and takes 5 times longer to boot (even with Fast Startup). It also uses twice the memory and 5 time the CPU at idle. Sometimes things come down to a "Bigger isn't always better" situation.

Comment: i agree with everything you have stated, however it must be given credit for the things it does properly - using whatever resources.

Comment: this has been a frustration with linux desktops forever. Everything is tiny. Window controls are tiny. Try all the themes. All the themes have tiny controls. All the themes are hideous.